# PHP - Remove leading and trailing spaces from XML tags

Tags: php, xml, yii

How to remove the leading and trailing white space between open and closing XML?

```
$sampleXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<note>
    <PersonName>
        <GivenName> David </GivenName>
        <MiddleName> Raj</MiddleName>
        <Affix>JR</Affix>
    </PersonName>
    <Aliases>
        <PersonName>
            <GivenName></GivenName>
            <MiddleName></MiddleName>
            <FamilyName></FamilyName>
        </PersonName>
    </Aliases>
    <DemographicDetail>
        <GovernmentId countryCode="US">testIDs data  </GovernmentId>
        <DateOfBirth>2000-12-12</DateOfBirth>
    </DemographicDetail>
</note>
<anothertag>
    <data type="credit">
        <Vendor score="yes"> vendor name  </Vendor>
    </data>
</anothertag>';


$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
foreach ($doc->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {

}
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$xml = $doc->saveXML($doc, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

I have tried using getElementsByTagName. But the tag name is dynamic. So it doesn't work for me in this case.

Is their any bulid in php class?

Expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<note>
    <PersonName>
        <GivenName>David</GivenName>
        <MiddleName>Raj</MiddleName>
        <Affix>JR</Affix>
    </PersonName>
    <Aliases>
        <PersonName>
            <GivenName></GivenName>
            <MiddleName></MiddleName>
            <FamilyName></FamilyName>
        </PersonName>
    </Aliases>
    <DemographicDetail>
        <GovernmentId countryCode="US">testIDs data</GovernmentId>
        <DateOfBirth>2000-12-12</DateOfBirth>
    </DemographicDetail>
</note>
<anothertag>
    <data type="credit">
        <Vendor score="yes">vendor name</Vendor>
    </data>
</anothertag>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse on all the nodes and trim the node value, for this you need a recursive function to traverse all the nodes:

```
function trimNodes(DOMNode $node) {
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child){
    if($child->hasChildNodes()) {
      trimNodes($child);
    } else{
      $child->nodeValue = trim($child->nodeValue);
    }
  }    
}
```

call this function and send the $doc to it, then you will have your expected XML.
Please note your XML needs to have a root node. You have two root nodes currently (anothertag, note), wrap them in one root node.

Answer (score 0):

If `$sampleXML` is just a string, then I think a **regular expression** could give you what you are looking for:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=\>)\s+(?=[a-zA-Z0-9,\.\_])|(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9,\.\_])\s+(?=\<)/';
$sampleXML = preg_replace($pattern, '', $sampleXML);
```